# How to include single quotes in Inno Setup while passing to function?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have used string in a function as follow.

I'm passing a string to a particular function, if that string has single quotes inside middle it's breaking. How to include single quotes in Inno Setup Pascal scripting?

```pascal
TempReadValue(StrArray, 'log4j.appender.testing.File=INSERT INTO emp select Eid,'%K','%L'from DistributionTable  whereEname = 'Nails:chino'', LogFileName);
```

When passing to function its taking till `%K`, after that its breaking. Can anybody guide me how to read/pass entire string till `Nils:chino`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
TempReadValue(StrArray, 'log4j.appender.testing.File=INSERT INTO emp select Eid,'+Chr(39)+'%K'+Chr(39)+','+Chr(39)+'%L'+Chr(39)+'from DistributionTable  whereEname = '+Chr(39)+'Nails:chino'+Chr(39), LogFileName);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to double the single quote:

```pascal
TempReadValue(
  StrArray,
  'log4j.appender.testing.File=INSERT INTO emp select Eid,''%K'',''%L''from DistributionTable  whereEname = ''Nails:chino''',      
  LogFileName);
```

See https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse8.html